# Importing python functions that use ! Jupyter feature

Tags: python, syntax-error, jupyter

In a jupyter notebook cell I can write functions that use the `!` feature. For example:

```
def ls():
    !ls -la
```

However, since this includes non-python syntax, if I try to write this in a separate file and then import it, I get a SyntaxError.

Is there any way to ignore this error and import it anyway?

Comment: not sure if it qualifies for an answer: `!ls` is just a shortcut to magic `%sx ls`, which you can use in Python code.

Comment: This was just an example, I'm using things like `!tar`,`!aws s3`, `!du`, etc.

Comment: the same principle holds, `%sx tar <params>`, `%sx aws s3 <params>`, `%sx du`. Also, you can do things like `my_var =  !<command>`. In neither of those cases you can susbstitute parameters with variables, but if you need to do so you probably should use `os.system` or a similar function anyway

Comment: oh, and of course you cannot use it outside of Jupyter

Comment: I get invalid syntax error when I try to import a function into jupyter that has `%sx` as well. What I'm trying to do is define long jupyter-only functions, which include magics, outside of jupyter and then import them in.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong -  you're trying to import a Python module from Jupyter, and the module contains Jupyter magic? If this is the case, it should not work. Imports are handled by regular Python (not Jupyter), so magic commands should result in syntax error

Comment: Yes. So it's not possible to store functions with jupyter magics in an auxiliary file?

Comment: Correct, it is not possible.

Comment: Really, why would you do that? There's no good reason to use any of this syntactic sugar; bite the bullet and switch to Doing It Right with `subprocess.run()`.